# Django POST data from admin not being displayed

Tags: python, django, database, request, http-post

So I have looked over this so many times now and cannot seem to find the issue for the life of me.

Not only does it not display the database information that it queried for, I cannot seem to add anything to it through the form.

The views.py method I have is supposed to either render all the info into the divs, yet it renders the right amount of divs with no information in it.
Also, the post request goes through as i can see on cmd, but the database remains unchanged, and no changes are made to the HTML.

please i could use some help.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Note
def notes(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_note = request.objects.all()
        Note.objects.add(new_note)
    return render(request, "notebook/notes.html", {
        "notes": Note.objects.all()
    })
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Note(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{Note.title}  {Note.content}"
```

layout.html(just the relevant part)

```
<div class="card content">
            <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold;"> Post A New Note </h4>
            <form action="{% url 'notebook:notes' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
               <div class="input"> Note  Title </div>
               <div><input name="title" style="margin-top: -10px;"></div>
                <div class="input">Note Content </div>
                <div><input class="note_txt" name="content"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    
                    <input class="btn" type="submit" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                        
                        
                    <a class="btn rounded" id="close_btn" style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 20px; right: 0%;">X</a>
                    
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

notes.html

```
{% block body %}
        {% for note in notes %}
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 mx-auto my-1 rounded note" style="min-height: 200px; min-width: 400px; background-color: #F2DCAC; border: 1px solid gray;">
                <div class="row" style="justify-content: center; font-size: 20; font-weight: light;">{{ Note.title }}</div>
                <div class="col-12">{{ Note.content }}</div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 

app_name = "notebook"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.notes , name = "notes"),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the data from the `request.POST` dictionary like this:

```
def notes(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        content = request.POST.get('content') # <- here
        title = request.POST.get('title') # <- here
        Note.objects.create(title=title, content=content)
    return render(request, "notebook/notes.html", {
        "notes": Note.objects.all()
    })
```

But, please consider using [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/), which contains form validation and many more features which might come handy in future. You can implement it like this:

```
# forms.py

from django import forms

class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Note
       fields = '__all__'

# view
from .forms import NoteForm


def notes(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, "notebook/notes.html", {
        "notes": Note.objects.all()
    })
```

### Update

You need to change the variables in template from:

```
<div class="col-12">{{ Note.title }}</div> 
<div class="col-12">{{ Note.content }}</div>
```

to

```
<div class="col-12">{{ note.title }}</div>
<div class="col-12">{{ note.content }}</div>
```

Comment: I changed the post request part and it is finally adding new info and the div properly. But it still isn't showing the text in the divs. I'd think it was an issue with the render request or passing in the variables, but any guess is good as mine right now.

Comment: wow thanks I cant believe it was just a case issue.

Answer (score 0):

After going through all problem. I found a little mistake in views.py file may be you are not saving objects that's why your database is empty, Otherwise there is no issue in your code.

```
   For reference:- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/
```